# Is it feasible to store a string which includes a space to the variable in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to put my `~/Library/Application Support/` directory to a variable in my ~/.bash_profile` to make it easier to reference from within Terminal. I first attempted to define it as follows:

`export L=~/Library/Application\ Support`

However, when I tried to `source ~/.bash_profile` and then called `ls $L`, I got an error: `/Users/username/Library/Application: Not a directory`.

However, no matter how I define it I cannot define it properly, as far as I came up with the way to define it. Here's the list that I tried, but none of them worked properly.

`~/Library/Application Support`
`"~/Library/Application Support"`
`"~/Library/Application\ Support"`

So is it feasible to store a string which includes a whitespace to a variable in bash to begin with?

Comment: Mind you, you don't want a literal `~` to be in your paths, as it's a shell expansion, and can't be used in a great many places (where such expansions aren't honored). Use `export L="$HOME/Library/Application Support"`, or `export L=~/"Library/Application Support"` (since the `~` isn't quoted in this case, it's expanded by the shell before assignment).

Comment: To provide a more concrete example -- if you run `ls "$L"` with `$L` containing literally `~/Library/Application Support`, `ls` will be looking for a directory named `~`, which doesn't exist. Your original export doesn't have that problem, because it doesn't quote or escape the `~` (but only escapes the space later), so the shell will replace it with `/Users/username`.

Comment: By the way -- if you're only setting this for use inside the terminal, you don't need to `export` it at all. `export` is for variables you're putting into the environment so processes you start from the shell can use them; if you only want to set a variable for use by the shell, you can put it in `~/.bashrc` instead, and need not use `export`.

Comment: Charles, I'm not sure I got what you're saying. Is the `~` expanded when `source ~/.bash_profile` is called? Or when `ls "$L"` is called? Also, is there any way to use `ls $L` (instead of `ls "$L"`) in this case?

Comment: When you do `ls "$L"`, with the quotes, you're **preventing** the `~` from being expanded at that time, so it *must* be expanded previously, when it's defined. And no, you can't use `ls $L` safely in any POSIX-compliant shell. (You can do it in zsh, but zsh isn't POSIX-compliant).

Comment: (...yet another aside: It's actually conventional to use lower-case variable names for things that are neither built-ins or environment variables; that way, you avoid the risk of overwriting names which *are* reserved by mistake. I've seen enough people use `for PATH in */*.txt` in their scripts and wonder why nothing else works after that point, when `for path in */*.txt` would be fine).

Comment: Charles, ah, OK, thanks. That's why `"~/Library/Application Support"` doesn't work!

Comment: Exactly! I do suggest using `$HOME` rather than `~`, as in `"$HOME/Library/Application Support"`, as the general habit to get into when scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `export` statement is fine; the space is properly escaped. You just need to quote the expansion of the parameter, so that `bash` gives a single argument to the `ls` command:

```
ls "$L"
```

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't able to come up with the idea that it's the calling side that has to be enclosed. Thanks.